# Is it possible prevent copying of resources to build directory in Gradle project and directly use them from original location?

Tags: gradle, micronaut

I come from Grails background and there was a feature where our changes to CSS, HTML & JS files were instant and didn't needed rebuilding code again.

Now, while building a Micronaut project I would like to have something similar but I am unable to figure how to configure Gradle for same.

Till now, I found out if I make changes to copied resources inside **build** folder, changes are reflected on browser and don't require rebuilding code but this forces me to do changes to original file later.

Can I somehow make Gradle directly use **src/main/resources** from it's original location rather than Gradle copying it to **build** folder?

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for `./gradlew run --continuous` but depending on what things you are changing in the `resources/` folder, those changes may nor may not affect the running app without restart.

More information is available at https://docs.micronaut.io/1.1.2/guide/index.html#reloading.

I hope that helps.

Comment: Sadly, I already went through the documentation but it does not solve my problem, one problem with above approach is micronaut session, I am forced to login again every time application starts. 
Also having static images ( about 400 MB folder ) inside resource folder also slows down the startup time drastically which makes hot reloading more of a problem rather than benefit.

Comment: "...one problem with above approach is micronaut session, I am forced to login again every time application starts..." - there is no way around that, but using `--continuous` doesn't cause the application to restart.  It causes Gradle to run the build continuously, which is a separate thing than restarting the app.